# why CSVN do not run anymore?

Tags: web-server, centos5

An unknown service is causing the server to crash.

I then stopped and started those services, but the CSVN does not run and makes the server slow when I start the service.

When I do a rollback this warning comes up:

**WARNING: CSVN Console timed-out waiting for http://localhost:3343/csvn**

I know must restart some service but which one?

the server is **centos5**

and additionaly CSVN from **COLABNET** NEED **JAVA SERVICE**

addition : when install the **Colabnet Subvertion Edge** it install its own web service

and i kill all them but know cant start it , i mean do not know where to go and do run this service;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restart the server then its work corectly

Answer (score 0):

It seems some issue with Network configuration. I had same issue, what I did is to add localhost.localdomain in /etc/hosts file against 127.0.1.1 and it started working.